# При попытке парсинга кода регулярными выражениями выводится ошибка

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re, лексер

Я делаю скриптовый язык, и у меня проблема разбиения кода на токены. У меня есть файл Lexer.py:

```
from game.sl.TokenType import token_types_list
from game.sl.Token import *
class Lexer:
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code
        self.pos = 0
        self.token_list = []

    def lex_analysis(self):
        while self.next_token():
            self.next_token()
        self.token_list = self.filter_list()
        return self.token_list

    def filter_list(self):
        """
        Фильтруем список токенов от пробелов
        """
        token_list = []
        for token in self.token_list:
            if token.type != token_types_list['SPACE']:
                token_list.append(token)
        return token_list

        def next_token(self):
        """
        Функция для разбиения кода на токены 
        Мы берем из типа токена его регулярное выражение, смотрим, совпадает ли 
        он с текущим токеном, и если да, то делаем новый токен, если нет, 
        то берем новую регулярку из словаря и 
        повторяем до тех пор, пока не закончится код 
        """
        if self.pos >= len(self.code):
            return False
        for token_type in token_types_list.values():
            result = re.match(r'^' + token_type.regex, self.code[int(self.pos):])
            if result and result.group(0):
                token = Token(token_type, result.group(0), self.pos)
                self.pos += len(result.group(0))
                self.token_list.append(token)
                return True
```

Также имеется файл TokenType.py, в котором задаются все типы токенов, которые будут использоваться в языке:

```
class TokenType:

    def __init__(self, name, regex):
        self.name = name
        self.regex = regex


token_types_list = {
    'PLUS': TokenType('PLUS', r'+'),
    'MINUS': TokenType('MINUS', r'-'),
    'ASSIGN': TokenType('ASSIGN', r'='),
    'CONDITIONAL': TokenType('CONDITIONAL', r'if'),
    'EQUAL': TokenType('EQUAL', r'=='),
    'COLON': TokenType('COLON', r':'),
    'COMMA': TokenType('COMMA', r','),
    'SEMICOLON': TokenType('SEMICOLON', r';'),
    'SET_IMAGE': TokenType('SET_IMAGE', r'set_image'),
    'SET_SPRITES': TokenType('SET_SPRITES', r'set_sprites'),
    'SET_SPRITE': TokenType('SET_SPRITE', r'set_sprite'),
    'SET_AUDIO': TokenType('SET_AUDIO', r'set_audio'),
    'MIX_AUDIO': TokenType('MIX_AUDIO', r'mix_audio'),
    'SET_TEXT': TokenType('SET_TEXT', r'set_text'),
    'ADD_DIALOG': TokenType('ADD_DIALOG', r'add_dialog'),
    'SPACE': TokenType('SPACE', r'[ \n\t\r]'),
    'LPAR': TokenType('LPAR', r'\('),
    'RPAR': TokenType('RPAR', r'\)'),
    'STRING': TokenType('STRING', r'".*"'),
    'NUMBER': TokenType('NUMBER', r'[0-9]*'),
    'VARIABLE': TokenType('VARIABLE', r'\w*'),
}
```

И, собственно, конструктор токена в файле Token.py:

```
from game.sl.TokenType import *

class Token:

    def __init__(self, type: TokenType, text, pos):
        self.type = type
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
```

На вход лексер получает такой исходный код:

```
set_image "resources/arts/street.img";
set_audio "resources/audio/street.mp3";
set_text "Text";
choice = add_dialog "first" "second" "third";
```

Но при запуске лексера выводится ошибка:

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 1
```

Если посмотреть, что прилетает в re.match, то получится такой текст:

```
print('^' + token_type.regex, ' ', self.code[self.pos:], ' ', self.pos)

# ^+   set_image "resources/arts/street.img";
# set_audio "resources/audio/street.mp3";
# set_text "Text";
# choice = add_dialog "first" "second" "third";   0
```

Почему она появляется?

Comment: Ошибка видимо в той строке где `re.match`. Выведите перед этой строкой на печать всё, что там участвует, все переменные. И нам покажите что там. Тогда будет гораздо понятнее что происходит.

Comment: Добавил, что прилетает в re.match

Comment: Я понял в чем причина. Если кому надо: ошибка прилетала, когда цикл доходил до +, -, =. и т.д. Я просто поставил перед ними \ и все заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял в чем причина. Ошибка прилетала, когда цикл доходил до +, -, =, и т.д.

Я просто поставил перед ними \ и все заработало.